# Custom Drill No Longer Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

We have been running a custom drill codeset to handle having multiple series that may or may not have a drillable node. Since version 2.1.6 of HighStock we have seen the case where if `category[0]` did not have any drillable items and we clicked on a category (say `category[7]`) and it has 2 children, each of which have children. Then we click through each child to the last item. What should happen is that it sees that this node has no children and it should reset the chart to initial state. It does this, but it then marks the first to categories on the intial load as having children when it doesn't. Then a user thinks they can click on it. This issue cascades down the drilled nodes such that whenever a category index was flagged as having a child it is then always flagged as having a child.

A visual representation is better to explain this.

The working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/7yd6v8Lq/

Non-working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/taay2p9z/

Click on the "Manufacturing" bars. Then click on "Durable Goods" bars. Then click on "Wood Product Manufacturing". This brings back to the initial chart state. For the working chart it looks the same.
For the non-working example note that upon click of "Durable Goods" that "Wood Product Manufacturing" appears to have children, then you click on it and it returns you to the initial set of data where "Total Nonfarm" and "Total Private" now appear as having children.

How can I prevent this under the latest version of Highcharts/stock?

Comment: So the issue is that in http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/taay2p9z/ the "Wood Product Manufacturing" is underlined, which means that has children. But in the reality has no children, that is correct?

Comment: Correct. It looks like the category labeling is not being cleared when the new category array is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `H.Tick.prototype.drillable` function you can add information to check point.drilldown. If extists then print underlined label.

Wrapped code:

```
H.Tick.prototype.drillable = function () {
    var pos = this.pos,
        label = this.label,
        axis = this.axis,
        ddPointsX = axis.ddPoints && axis.ddPoints[pos];


    if (this.drilldown && label && ddPointsX && ddPointsX.length) {
        if (!label.basicStyles) {
            label.basicStyles = H.merge(label.styles);
        }
        label
            .addClass('highcharts-drilldown-axis-label')
            .css(axis.chart.options.drilldown.activeAxisLabelStyle)
            .on('click', function () {
                axis.drilldownCategory(pos);
            });

    } else if (label && label.basicStyles) {
        label.styles = {}; // reset for full overwrite of styles
        label.css(label.basicStyles);
        label.on('click', null); // #3806           
    }
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/taay2p9z/7/

Comment: I am already doing some checks in a prototype so i added this in that code block. Thanks!